# Small error in employer's name for CPT application

Tags: immigration

I'm an international grad student in USA. I will be starting my summer internship at "XYZ Technology".

However, on my new I-20 there seems to be a small clerical error. The employer's name is printed as "XYZ Technologies".

I know, it sounds small, but I was wondering, if this could pose a problem for me.